# What is the easiest way to represent a DFA transition table in C# code?

Tags: c#, dictionary, state-machine, finite-automata, dfa

Here is what I go so far, so in DFAs right, you have states and you have transitions between those states, to go from `state A` to `state B` you consume a `symbol ex: 'a'`. Now I am trying to write a `DFA transition function` that takes a `current state (int) and a transition symbol (char) and returns the next state (int)`, Now to do that you have to have access to a transition table, now what is the best way to represent that transition table, Here is what I got so far:

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<char, int>> transitionMap = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<char, int>>();
```

that is my transition map, it's a dictionary where the first `int key is current state` and `nested dictionary consists of symbol consumed and the other int is the next state that I have to return`, The problem I'm running into is that a dictionary Can't have duplicate keys (in this case state) and DFAs can have multiple transitions for same state. For example, if I try to do this:

```
  Dictionary<char, int> dict = new Dictionary<char, int>();
  dict.Add('a', 1);  // 'a' here is the symbol consumed to go to state 1 from state 0
  transitionMap.Add(0, dict); // 0 is the current state
```

Now when I add this, It works, but when I try to add another transition for state 0, It doesn't because Dictionaries can't have duplicate keys, So what to do here?

Comment: FWIW, I've used this library for building simple state machines and it puts a nice interface on top of it: https://github.com/dotnet-state-machine/stateless

Comment: Lol, nice @NateBarbettini

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, so I had a problem understanding dictionaries, I got it now:

```
if (transitionMap.ContainsKey(state))
{
      Dictionary<char, int> res = new Dictionary<char, int>();   
      transitionMap.TryGetValue(state, out res);
      res.Add(symbol, nextState);
      transitionMap[state] = res;
}
```

I just had to check if It the state existed, then grab the the dictionary, add another transition to it and add to the transitionMap.